# Twig: Change or alias built-in tag names?

Tags: symfony, twig

Is it possible to easily change (or provide an alias to) a built-in tag name in Twig? For example, I'd like to be able to use the word `slot` instead of `block` in my templates (e.g. `{% slot mypage %}{% endslot %}` instead of `{% block mypage %}{% endblock %}`).

This page: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax ... shows how to easily change the tag markers (`{%` and `%}`), but I would like to change an actual tag *name*. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just go with `block`?

Comment: @DarkBee, I am building a system that already uses the term "block" to mean something else, and I think it will create confusion for the people who have to work with the twig templates if the term "block" means two different things. Of course I can change my own usage of "block" to something else, but it makes perfect sense for the domain, whereas the term "block" in the twig template sense seems rather arbitrary to me and I think it would actually make their purpose clearer to call it something else like "slot" or "placeholder", etc.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, but you should define custom [tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#tags) which extend `Twig_TokenParser_Block` and override methods `decideBlockEnd` and `getTag`.

```
public function decideBlockEnd(Twig_Token $token)
{
    return $token->test('endslot');
}

public function getTag()
{
    return 'slot';
}
```

Maybe custom `Twig_Node` type will be necessary too.

After that, you need create and register [twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).